# Downloading from Google Docs using an Uri containing access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm creating a viewer app for Windows Phone 7. The app already handles the OAuth2 stuff and succesfully browses Google Doc's folder structure.

I use [Google Documents List API 3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list). BTW browsing works perfectly without using request headers, instead I append the access_token to the request Uri.

Now the app needs to show files to the user, if possible without downloading them first. This means that I want to set the UI's Image.Source to the Uri of an image, the UI's MediaElement.Source to the Uri of a video and the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Track.Source to the Uri of an audio file. Obviously I can't use request headers in this scenario.

However it seems that simply appending the access_token to the download Uri doesn't work. The UI elements fail with generic error messages, and if I manually try with a web browser (which isn't logged in to Google) it shows an empty screen, a 401 error or it redirects to Google's login page.

Is it possible to download/stream a Google Data entry just by defining the Uri? If yes, what does the Uri need to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for authorization using the access_token URL parameter has not been allowed on purpose for security reasons. Basically if a user would be to open a malicious file on a browser (e.g html containing some Javascript would suffice) the malicious code on the file could steal the access token in the URL and send it to a third party bad guy.

To access the file you need to authorize using "Authorization" HTTP header. Simply add an HTTP header to the request which is like:

```
Authorization: Bearer access_token_here
```

Comment: The security issue is a good point. Unfortunately I can't use headers without rewriting the operating system ;-) Alternatively I could download the file prior to showing it, which e.g. in the case of a movie is far from ideal ... Thank you!

Comment: We know this is a pain point for many developers. Especially because proxying the file server-side is not always a realistic option (e.g. your example of movies). We are investigating some other ways of authorizing, for example using the Google secured login cookie (so if the user is signed-in he would have access to the file without using OAuth 2.0). But no promises at this point. It will depend on priorities and also security issues.